# Линейное преобразование в ГОСТ Р 34.12-2015

Tags: математика, криптография

Здравствуйте!

Мне хочется написать реализацию недавно принятого на вооружение симметричного блочного алгоритма шифрования "Кузнечик". Сейчас изучаю стандарт, пытаюсь посчитать каждый шаг алгоритма  "на пальцах" чтобы подтвердить своё понимание, и один момент никак не сходится с тестовым примером.

Текст ГОСТа представлен на сайте ТК 26: http://tc26.ru/standard/gost/GOST_R_3412-2015.pdf

**О чём речь?**

Проблема в трансформации `R`, которая преобразует 16-байтный массив, а точнее — в `l`, которая из этого массива получает всего один байт данных.

```
R(a[]) = l(a[]) & a[15] & a[14] & .. & a[1]
l(a[]) = 148 * a[15] + 32 * a[14] + ... + 1 * a[0]
```

> Операции сложения и умножения осуществляются в поле *F*, а константы являются элементами поля в указанном ранее смысле.

Как я понял, речь идёт <s>о сложении и умножении по модулю 255</s>:

> *F* конечное поле *GF*(2)[x]∕p(x), где p(x) = x8 + x7 + x6 + x + 1 ∈ *GF*(2)[x]

**Что случилось?**

В приложении к стандарту приводятся контрольные примеры для преобразований, используемых в алгоритме шифрования, и для `R` в том числе.

```
R(00000000000000000000000000000100) = 94000000000000000000000000000001
R(94000000000000000000000000000001) = a5940000000000000000000000000000
```

Шестнадцатеричные числа — представление массива из 16 байт, причём первый (а точнее, нулевой) элемент находится в конце строки.

Итак, `R(a[]) = l(a[]) & a[15] & ... & a[1]`

В первом примере всё хорошо:

```
l(a[]) = 148 * a[1] = 148 = 0x94
R(a[]) = 0x94 & a[15..1] = 0x94, 0x00, ... 0x01
```

Во втором случае всё сложнее. <s>Если я правильно понял про сложение и умножение, озвученное выше, то:</s>

```
l(a[]) = 148 * a[15] + 1 * a[0] 
       = (148 * 148) mod 255 + 1 * 1 
       = 229 + 1 = 230 = E6

R(a[]) = 0xE6, 0x94, 0x00, ...
```

Стоп! В контрольном примере старшие байты получились 0xA5, 0x94!

**Что делать?**

Собственно, вот и сам вопрос :)

*В какое место в моём потоке сознания прокралась ошибка и результат функции во `l()` втором примере оказался не тем, каким надо, и что сделать, чтобы всё закончилось хорошо?*

**Обновление №1**

Как оказалось, умножение в поле — совсем не "просто умножить и взять остаток от деления", а целая процедура, подробно описанная в [GF(256) finite field multiplication function in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13239816/gf256-finite-field-multiplication-function-in-c-sharp).

Более того, сложение в поле GF(2^n) оказалось простым XOR'ом.

Итого для второго примера получилось:

```
l(a[]) = (148 * 0x94) + (1 * 0x01) = 0x91 + 0x01 = 0x90
```

Что в общем-то всё ещё далеко от `A5`.

Привожу код расчёта `l()`:

```
byte[] l_mul = { 1, 148, 32, 133, 16, 194, 192, 1, 251, 1, 192, 194, 16, 133, 32, 148 };

public byte l (byte[] a) {
   byte p = 0x00;
   for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
     p ^= gf.Mul(l_mul[i], a[i]);
   }
   return p;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем, проблема была в процедуре умножения в поле. Если результат умножения полиномов получается слишком большой и не входит в *GF*(256), то его [надо поделить](http://www.cs.utsa.edu/~wagner/laws/FFM.html) на некоторый неприводимый полином.

В [примере из Википедии](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field_arithmetic#C_programming_example) и [упомянутом ранее вопросе](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13239816/gf256-finite-field-multiplication-function-in-c-sharp) на Stack Overflow используется полином `x^8 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1` (`100011011b` = `0x11b` или `0x1b`), который применяется в AES.

В случае же ГОСТа из определения поля *F* необходимо использовать другой полином: `x^8 + x^7 + x^6 + x + 1` = `0x1c3` или `0xc3`. Теперь с контрольными примерами всё сходится :)

```
public byte MulSlow (byte a, byte b) {
    byte p = 0;
    byte counter;
    byte hi_bit_set;
    for (counter = 0; counter < 8 && a != 0 && b != 0; counter++) {
        if ((b & 1) != 0)
            p ^= a;
        hi_bit_set = (byte)(a & 0x80);
        a <<= 1;
        if (hi_bit_set != 0)
            a ^= 0xc3; /* x^8 + x^7 + x^6 + x + 1 */
        b >>= 1;
    }
    return p;
}
```